# Why journey builder with Update Contact Data doesn´t work?

Tags: marketing-cloud, update

We have created a Journey Builder with splits and Update contact Data.
This Journey is triggered by Fire event in automation, and have data in a Data Extension.
The splits uses fields form this Data Extension and Update contact Data modifies another fields from this Data Extension:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1EBHQJZR2PRUWdoc2dfMEJHTVU/edit?usp=sharing

We can see that the trigger has fired, but the fields have no changes. Why?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Are you seeing any errors in the Browser's Developer "Console" or "Network" tab?

Typically looking for 40x or 500 errors in the browser is a good place to start.

If you can share that information, we can dig a bit deeper to resolve this.